# Neo4j: what is the most efficient solution to import csv?

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, cypher, load

I have the following code and I need to use (if exists) a code more efficient because I have a lot of rows in my csv and Neo4j takes too much time to add all rows.

```
using periodic commit 1000
load csv with headers from "file:///registry_office.csv" as f 
 fieldterminator "|" 
 WITH f AS a
WHERE NOT a.JobName IS NULL and NOT a.JobCode IS NULL and NOT 
 a.JobDescription IS NULL and NOT a.JobLongDescription IS NULL 
 AND NOT a.Long_Description IS NULL AND NOT a.Position IS NULL 
 AND NOT a.birthDate IS NULL AND NOT a.startWorkingDate IS NULL
merge (b:Job{Name:a.JobName, Code:a.JobCode, Job:a.JobDescription, 
 JobLongDescription:a.JobLongDescription})
merge (c:Person{PersonName:a.PersonName, PersonSurname:a.PersonSurname, 
 CF:a.CF, birthDate:a.birthDate, address:a.address, age:a.age, 
 married:a.married, birthPlace:a.a.birthPlace})
merge (b)<-[:RELATED_TO{startWorkingDate:a.startWorkingDate, 
 JobPosition:a.Position}]-(c) 
return *;
```

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: have you created some constraints in your graph ?  Can yougive the `EXPLAIN` of your query ?

Comment: Also include your neo4j version

Comment: Yes, I created constraints and index and I have the last version of Neo4j.

Comment: Please add EXPLAIN to the start of your cypher, and share the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [import tool](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/tools/import/) is generally much faster than `LOAD CSV`.

However, your query suggests that each csv row ends as a pattern (b)<--(c), so you'd need to to some pre-processing on this csv... first filter null values, then split into 3 csvs (2 for nodes, 1 for relationships).

To do this, you have 3 main options:

- **Excel** - not viable for huge CSVs
- **CLI tool** - something like [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/)
- **Program** - if you are OK with Python or JavaScript, you'll be able to do this in 20m or so.